# css locator to navigate to parent tag from child and css locator to identify sub string in a attribute

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm  good  at writing **XPATH** locators but for my new project i have to write locators using **CSS**

i have 2 doubts

1)

[image]

from the above code i have to identify **div** with **id** contains value "**col3**"

in **xpath** i can write **//div[contains(@id,'col3')]**

in **css** i tried below locators

**css=#id:contains('col3')**

**css=div:contains(#id,'col3')**
but none of them working.

please help me with **CSS** locator to identify **id** contains value "**col3**"

2)

[image]

i have to navigate from one attribute to its parent attribute.

i.e., from "Form tag i have to navigate ti its parent div tag"

in **XPATH //form[@id='comment-form']/../**

help me to navigate using **CSS**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this for 1st one
css=div[id*='col3']

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your first problem is:

```
div[id*='col3']
```

Referring to [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), I do not think there is any solution for your 2nd problem.  You might have to use xpath here.